# Is there an existing way to generate wiring code from a spring application context?

Tags: spring

I want to remove spring from a little library that really doesn't need it in favour of wiring the classes together in code. I feel it should be possible to auto-generate the code to stick the library together using the same logic Spring does to do it at runtime. Does code to do this already exist?

(Of course it might be more complicated for any AOP type stuff Spring is doing - but when it's just vanilla instantiation and autowiring it should be relatively simple?)

Comment: [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) is a compile-time dependency injection framework with a smaller footprint, it might be helpful.

Comment: The only dependency injection framework this needs is the ability to pass arguments to methods and constructors.